# How to create an amazon Fire TV virtual device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, amazon-fire-tv

**EDIT:**

After searching for a while it seems that currently there is no way of creating a virtual device of a Fire TV

---

I am trying to create an amazon virtual device using AVD Manager, but I am not being able to find a correct image.

I followed the steps detailed here:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/setting-up-your-development-environment

But they dont specify anything about creating a test device.

Also here:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/testing-without-an-amazon-device

Says:

```
The steps described here cannot be used to simulate the Fire TV.
```

But never provides a link to a documentation about how to do it.

Could it be that there is not way to create a virtual Fire TV?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @osiris355 No, there is no way to simulate a fire tv device. The cheapest option would be buying a fire stick :P

Answer (score 1):

I found an official document to test fire tv application without devices, see [this link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/fire-app-builder-use-an-android-tv-emulator), I just list the important steps as follows:

> To set up an Android TV emulator for your app:
>
> 1. Go to Tools > Android > AVD Manager, or click the AVD Manager button  on the top navigation bar.
> 2. Click the + Create Virtual Device button.  Note: You can select one of the default TV profiles, or you can customize the settings by
>    following the steps below. If you select a default TV profile, skip
>    ahead to step 12 where you select a system image.
> 3. In the Category column, select TV.
> 4. Click the New Hardware Profile button.
> 5. In the Device Name, type something like fire_tv_emulator. (Avoid using parentheses in the name, as this may cause errors.)
> 6. For the Device Type, select Android TV.
> 7. For the Screen size, type the screen size you want (for example, 40).
> 8. For the Resolution, type the resolution you want (for example, 1280 x 720).
> 9. For the Supported device states, select only Landscape (clear the Portrait check box).
> 10. Click Finish.
> 11. In the “Choose a device definition” dialog box, select the emulator you just created and click Next.
> 12. In the Release Name column, select at least Marshmallow API Level 23 or higher. If you haven’t downloaded this system image yet, click
>     Download to download it. (If you select API Level 22 or lower, media
>     playback will fail in the emulator.)
> 13. Click Next and then click Finish.

Comment: This is still running Googles flavor of Android. It will not be fire os nor allow the developer to test any Amazon apis/sdks.